# Running ELK stack docker on host machine

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, networking, containers, kibana

I want to install elasticsearch and kibana, on dockers, on my host machine:

```
    $sudo docker run -dit --name elasticsearch -h elasticsearch --net host -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -v $(pwd)/elasticsearch/data/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/ -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:6.6.1
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode


    $sudo docker run -dit --name kibana -h kibana --net host -p 5601:5601 kibana:6.6.1
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode
```

and I get the following errors on kibana:

```
 log   [14:32:26.655] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/
 log   [14:32:26.656] [warning][admin][elasticsearch] No living connections
```

But If I don't use host machine:

```
sudo docker network create mynetwork
sudo docker run -dit --name elasticsearch -h elasticsearch --net mynetwork -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -v $(pwd)/elasticsearch/data/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/ -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:6.6.1
sudo docker run -dit --name kibana -h kibana --net mynetwork -p 5601:5601 kibana:6.6.1
```

all working fine. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`--net host` disables most of the Docker networking stack.  Basic features like communicating between containers using their container name as a host name don’t work.  Except in very unusual circumstances it’s never necessary.

Your second setup that uses standard Docker networking and publishes selected ports through the host is a best practice.

Comment: Thanks again @David Maze, you know your stuff.... When I create network, I can access via dockers with the same network. The problem is that I have kubernetes installed on the same computer, and I want that container inside a pod to run $telnet to logstash. The problem is that I have permission denied, because its diffrent  networks. I don't understand how to allow kubernetes pod to run telnet to logstash.

Comment: You can use the Kubernetes downward API to get the node’s name and/or IP address into a pod, and then use that to reach the published ports.  A better option is to migrate all of this to run in Kubernetes, and then you can reach it using the standard Service interface.

Comment: But how hard is to do the first option? Because if its not too hard, it would be preferred.

Comment: “Get the node’s IP address” is the specific example in [the Kubernetes downward API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables).